# Inconsistent Out-of-bag error estimates

Tags: r, caret, out-of-sample

I keep getting different out-of-bag error estimates from the `caret` package, depending on how the estimates are computed. I can't seem to nail down exactly where the discrepancy is coming from.

Consider a simple random forest model using the built-in `mtcars` dataset:

```
set.seed(100)
tc <- caret::trainControl( method="oob" )
m <- caret::train( mpg ~ ., data=mtcars, method="rf", trControl=tc )
# Random Forest 

# 32 samples
# 10 predictors

# No pre-processing
# Resampling results across tuning parameters:

#   mtry  RMSE      Rsquared 
#    2    2.429726  0.8322324
#    6    2.301918  0.8494180
#   10    2.429676  0.8322394

# RMSE was used to select the optimal model using  the smallest value.
# The final value used for the model was mtry = 6.
```

A print out of the model reports that `mtry = 6` was the best meta-parameter value and the associated error estimates are `RMSE = 2.301918` and `R^2 = 0.8494180`. My understanding is that these error estimates are computed over out-of-bag examples in the data due to `trainControl( method="oob" )` setting. Is this correct?

If I now apply the `oob()` function from `$modelInfo` to the best model (as captured by `$finalModel`), I would expect to get the same performance estimates as the `mtry=6` entry in the table above, but I don't:

```
m$modelInfo$oob( m$finalModel )
#      RMSE  Rsquared 
# 2.3485040 0.8432614
```

Furthermore, if I now compute `predict( m$finalModel )`, it [should return out-of-bag predictions, since `newdata` parameter is omitted](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/randomForest/versions/4.6-12/topics/predict.randomForest). However, this results in yet another estimate of OOB error when passed to `postResample`:

```
caret::postResample( predict(m$finalModel), mtcars$mpg )
#      RMSE  Rsquared       MAE 
# 2.3485040 0.8468821 1.8463368
```

(Notice that although `RMSE` agrees with the `oob()` call above, `R^2` has a different value.)

While I appreciate that the values are in the same "ballpark", I don't understand where the discrepancy comes from. Does anybody have any insight?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems to be impossible to get to the tuning resamples if you use `oob` as a method, unless you [write a custom method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26845933/caret-is-it-possible-to-save-each-models-from-tuning) that saves away the fit objects during tuning.

```
  library(caret)
  # Copy all model structure info from existing model type
  cust.mdl <- getModelInfo("rf", regex=FALSE)[[1]]

  # Override fit function so that we can save the iteration
  cust.mdl$fit <- function(x=x, y=y, wts=wts, param=param, lev=lev, last=last, classProbs=classProbs, ...) {
    # Dont save the final pass (dont train the final model across the entire training set)
    if(last == TRUE) return(NULL) 
    # Fit the model
    fit.obj <- getModelInfo("rf", regex=FALSE)[[1]]$fit(x, y, wts, param, lev, last, classProbs, ...)

    # Create an object with data to save and save it
    fit.data <- list(resample=rownames(x),
                   mdl=fit.obj,
                   #x, y, wts,
                   param=param, lev=lev, last=last, classProbs=classProbs, 
                   other=list(...))

    # Create a string representing the tuning params
    param.str <- paste(lapply(1:ncol(param), function(x) {
                       paste0(names(param)[x], param[1,x])
                       }), collapse="-")

    save(fit.data, file=paste0("rf_model_", param.str, ".RData"))
  return (fit.obj)
}

set.seed(100)
tc <- trainControl( method="oob")
m <- train( mpg ~ ., data=mtcars, method=cust.mdl, trControl=tc)
```

The final `fit` object returns oob errors from each tuning iteration

```
m$results
>
         RMSE  Rsquared mtry
    1 2.417379 0.8339331    2
    2 2.394624 0.8370448    6
    3 2.455534 0.8286495   1
```

So now if I fetch the `fit` object from the tuning iteration corresponding to `mtry=6`, I can recreate those errors

```
load("rf_model_mtry6.RData")

# using same oob() function that is used for final predictions
m$modelInfo$oob(fit.data$mdl)
>
     RMSE  Rsquared 
2.3946242 0.8370448
```

Comment: Thanks for this. I think I get it: the discrepancy comes from the fact that different data resampling is used for tuning the parameter grid as opposed to training the final model. I notice that using your approach still produces a different value for `caret::R2( predict(fit.data$mdl), mtcars$mpg )`. Any thoughts on why that might be happening? (The value from `caret::RMSE( predict(fit.data$mdl), mtcars$mpg )` matches exactly.)

Comment: I believe `rsq` is calculated using traditional formula and not corr.squared. Use `caret::R2(pred, obs, formula = "traditional")` if you want to recreate `rsquared` in resampling object

Comment: Ah, yep. I see it now: `caret::R2( predict(fit.data$mdl), mtcars$mpg, formula = "traditional" )` gives the same value.

Comment: @dmi3kno great answer but could you pls clarify one thing for less talented coders having troubles to reproduce this: what you show in your answer as the output of `m$result` is this in any way modified by your custom method or would I get the exact same output with the standard method `rf`? If it is the same, could one look up the final `mtry` value in the `bestTune` of the model and search for the corresponding row in this output such that no custom method would be required?